# Magento 2 phpcs coding standard rules cheatsheet

Tags: magento2.3, coding-standards

Has anyone got a cheat sheet style list of the common Magento 2 code quality exclusions?

```
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate.FoundThis
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Files.LineLength.MaxExceeded
```

etc

I've search online but I can't find anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put together something myself

```
// phpcs:ignoreFile
```

```php
$stuff = [1,2,3]; // phpcs:ignore
```

```
// phpcs:disable Generic,Squiz,Magento2
```

```
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Exceptions
```

```php
// phpcs:disable
$stuff = [1,2,3];
// phpcs:enable
```

```
// phpcs:disable Generic.Metrics.NestingLevel
// phpcs:disable Generic.CodeAnalysis.UselessOverridingMethod
// phpcs:disable Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent
```

```
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Classes.AbstractApi
// phpcs:disable Magento2.CodeAnalysis.EmptyBlock
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Exceptions.ThrowCatch
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Exceptions.DirectThrow
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
// phpcs:disable Magento2.PHP.ShortEchoSyntax.ShortEchoTag
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Security.IncludeFile
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Security.InsecureFunction
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate
```

```
// phpcs:disable Squiz.Commenting.ClassComment.Missing
// phpcs:disable Squiz.Functions.GlobalFunction
// phpcs:disable Squiz.PHP.GlobalKeyword.NotAllowed
// phpcs:disable Squiz.WhiteSpace.ScopeClosingBrace.ContentBefore
```